# Aggregate rows into new column based on common value in another column in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames
df1 is like this

```
| NOC  | 2007   | 2008  |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| A    | 100    | 5   | 
| B    | 100    | 5     | 
| C    | 100    | 5| 
| D    | 20    | 2     |
| E    | 10    | 12     |  
| F   | 2    | 1     |
```

df2

```
| NOC  | GROUP  | 
|:---- |:------:| 
| A    | aa| 
| B    | aa   | 
| C    | aa   |  
| D    | bb   | 
| E    | bb   | 
| F   | cc    |
```

I would like to create a new df3 which will aggregate the columns 2007 and 2008 based on Group identity by assigning the sum of rows with the same group identity, so my df3 would look like this

| NOC | 2007 | 2008 | GROUP | S2007 | s2008 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 5 | aa | 300 | 15 |
| B | 100 | 5 | aa | 300 | 15 |
| C | 100 | 5 | aa | 300 | 15 |
| D | 20 | 2 | bb | 30 | 14 |
| E | 10 | 12 | bb | 30 | 14 |
| F | 2 | 1 | cc | 2 | 1 |

my codes are not very efficient, I first merged df1 with df2 by NOC, into df3

```
df3<-merge(df1, df2, by="NOC",all.x=TRUE)
```

then used dprl summarised into df4 and created s2007 and s2008

```
df3 %>%
  group_by(GROUP) %>% 
  summarise(num = n(),
  s2017 = sum(2007),s2018 = sum(2008))->df3
```

then I merged df1 with df3 again to create my final database

I am wondering two problems:

1. is there a more efficient way?
2. since my dataframe contains annual data 2007-2030, currently I am writing out the summarize function for each year, is there a faster way of summarize all the columns except NOC?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before this, a small piece of advice, never name your columns in numeric, it may create you many glitches.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = 'NOC') %>%
  group_by(GROUP) %>%
  mutate(across(c(`2007`, `2008`), ~sum(.), .names = 's.{.col}' ))

# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   GROUP [3]
  NOC   `2007` `2008` GROUP s.2007 s.2008
  <chr>  <int>  <int> <chr>  <int>  <int>
1 A        100      5 aa       300     15
2 B        100      5 aa       300     15
3 C        100      5 aa       300     15
4 D         20      2 bb        30     14
5 E         10     12 bb        30     14
6 F          2      1 cc         2      1
```